# AjaxSubmit with window.location on response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, redirect, window.location

I have a problem with ajaxSubmit... The problem is that, when I submit a form and get a response from PHP that have a script with **window.location**, the page doesn't change at all...

My PHP script just returns a script with window.location when the form is submitted correctly, otherwise, it returns a JSON that is parsed on the success function.

Using the tools of Chrome, I see that it loads the window.location URL on the Network Tab but, it doesn't show it to the user...

Here's the code I have:

```
$("form").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("form").ajaxSubmit({
        success: function(resp){
            try{
                resp=JSON.parse(resp);
                alert(resp["error"]);
            } catch(e){
                $("<div></div>").html(resp);
            }

        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

How do I need to do to make it work? Is there any property of options parameter of AjaxSubmit that could solve that?

Comment: Can you post the content of the `resp` variable.

Comment: The `resp` variable contains the code of the URL indicated on `window.location`

Comment: OK, so how do you execute that code? At the minute you're just parsing it.

Comment: But the problem is that I want to parse the code that contains the window.location in order to execute it and change the current url of the browser. What is happening is that `resp` gets the code of the redirected page and not the code with `window.location`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just provide URL without JS code in your server answer and then execute :

```
$("form").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("form").ajaxSubmit({
        success: function(resp){
            try{
                resp=JSON.parse(resp);
                window.location.href = resp;
            } catch(e){
                $("<div></div>").html(resp);
            }

        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: So I should get rid of using `window.location` on the PHP side and instead of it, I should send a json with the URL to parse on the success function? Isn't there a way to call success before the execution of scripts that exists on the submitted URL?

Comment: No way, the submitted URL will always be executed before success callback will be called

Comment: Even the scripts inside of it?

Comment: Of course, the AJAX url is entire executed, then if HTTP return code 200, the success callback is called else error

Comment: But it works if I use `$.ajax` and not `$("form").ajaxSubmit()`... The problem is that I can't use `$.ajax` because I have file elements in the form...

Comment: So encapsulate the $.ajax call inside a $.submit event and return false to prevent submit default behaviour

Comment: It doesn't work with files on the form because I have no way to put them on the `data` option. That was the first thing I tried before AjaxSubmit. I could use `FileReader` but, it doesn't work on IE 8 and 9...